# How to do simple arithmetic with arguments in ConTeXt?

Tags: macros, context

This seems like a simple requirement but after reading the wiki and googling for answers, I can't figure how to express it for ConTeXt.

What I want to do is define a macro with two arguments (or one argument + a default value) n and m that repeats a symbol n times in one color and m-n times in another color. but how can I tell (Con)TeX(t) to subtract m-n instead of typing literally m-n?

Some pseudo-example of what I mean:

```
\define[2]\putsymbols{\dorecurse{#1}{Symbol-in-color-A}\dorecurse{#2-#1}{Symbol-in-color-B}}
```

so when I type `\putsymbols[3][5]`
it will produce 3 symbols in color A and 2 symbols in color B

Comment: Counting and arithmetic are different things. Anyway, PGF seems to support ConTeXt. See PGF manual **83 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement** and **88.1 Loading the Mathematical Engine**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is often easier to use a lua-based solution than to figure out TeX arithmetic.

```
\define\PutSymbols{\dodoubleempty\doPutSymbols}
\def\doPutSymbols[#1][#2]#3{\ctxlua{userdata.putsymbols(#1, #2, [===[#3]===])}}

\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}

  function userdata.putsymbols(n, m, s)
    for i = 1,n do
      context.color({"darkred"}, s)
    end
    for i = n+1,m do
      context.color({"darkblue"}, s)
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext
\PutSymbols[3][8]{*}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I tried this in my document where it goes inside a table and I get a Undefined control sequence error on the /stoptabulate. The table without the macro worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry, nevermind. I had a typo in the macro definition (ugh)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming I have understood what you're after... Here's a suggestion that may do what you want:

```
\def\PutSymbols{\dodoubleempty\doPutSymbols}

\def\doPutSymbols[#1][#2]#3{%
  \iffirstargument
     \dorecurse{\the\numexpr #1\relax}{\color[darkred]{#3}}
  \else
    \dorecurse{1}{#3}
  \fi%
  \ifsecondargument
    \dorecurse{\the\numexpr #2-#1\relax}{\color[darkblue]{#3}}
  \else
    \dorecurse{1}{\color[darkblue]{#3}}
  \fi%
}

\starttext

\PutSymbols[3][8]{*}

\stoptext
```

You may want to add a few checks to make sure that your input is valid (are the arguments numbers, i #2 > #1 etc.)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this inserts a space between the two sets?

Comment: Because I was too lazy to put a comment sign at all line endings...

Answer (score 2):

You can use classic plain TeX approach because ConTeXt knows plain TeX macros and TeX primitives:

```
\newcount\symbolnum  
\def\putsymbols[#1][#2]#3{%
   \symbolnum=0
   \loop              
      \advance\symbolnum by1
      \color[red]{#3}%
      \ifnum\symbolnum<#1 \repeat
   \it
   \loop
      \advance\symbolnum by1
      \color[blue]{#3}%
      \ifnum\symbolnum<#2 \repeat
}         
\putsymbols[3][7]{X}
```